# HTML::FormHandler just 1 option not rendering correctly

Tags: perl, render, forms, catalyst

I'm using [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler) and building the form dynamically like so:

```
my $form = HTML::FormHandler->new(
          name => 'types',
          field_list => [
              parent_id => {
                  type => 'Select',
                  label => 'Parent',
                  required => 1,
                  options => [{value=>'test',label=>'test'}],
              },
          ],
);
```

Whenever I only pass in one option like above, this is the output that is rendered for the form:

```
<select name="parent_id" id="parent_id">  
    <option id="parent_id.0" value="test">  </option>  
    <option id="parent_id.1" value="test">  </option>
</select>
```

However, the resulting output should be:

```
<select name="parent_id" id="parent_id">  
    <option id="parent_id.0" value="test">test</option>  
</select>
```

But once I add one more option, such as this:

```
options => [{value=>'test',label=>'test'},{value=>'test2',label=>'test2'}],
```

Then the output renders correctly and becomes:

```
<select name="parent_id" id="parent_id">  
    <option id="parent_id.0" value="test">test</option>  
    <option id="parent_id.1" value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
```

Is this a bug on `HTML::FormHandler`'s part, or is theres something I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: can't reproduce your problem on my mac 10.8.2, perl 5.16.1

Comment: @Alec, hmm interesting. I'm on centos 6.3 with perl 5.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the select type expects a minimum of two options. If you must use the select for a one option selection, and cannot use a checkbox or radio button (if for example the selection list is dynamically generated) could you set the first option to be a default non-value with a 'please select...' label.